# Transparency for object in solid viewport shading, vertex color type or x-ray for single object

Tags: vertices, transparency

Is there any way to make single object transparent while using solid viewport shading and vertex color type. [image: ---]

Or apply x-ray for single object?

Comment: I don't know of a way to do that in workbench, but it's easy to set up with Eevee.